# httpClient -> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, rest, httpclient, put, http-error

I'm allways getting this error (**HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**) when I'm trying to do a PUT/POST in my REST client application, using HttpClient.

Do you have any idea of what kind of error it can be? Isn't it a error in the code?
It tells that is in teh Server..
If you need some of my code, just ask for it!

Thanks

This is the message I receive in the server logs:

```
[#|2013-03-15T09:34:32.508+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=115;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7fd86c92; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2084)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:486)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2761)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:166)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Comment: do you have code of your service application? I don't think that this could be reproduce using client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server receives the request, but the logic that processes it (if java, a servlet) causes an error. You must get the server logs and look for stacktrace, error messages... etc.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2. How can I see that?

Comment: I solved the problem in another way, but read the server logs help me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've already solved my problem by do the PUT in a different way.

I was doing it like this:

```
    httpPut.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPut.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();

    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));

    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", "user1"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", "teste"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", "Alves"));

    httpPut.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

And now I'm doing this way:

```
        httpPut.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPut.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();  
            obj.put("userID", "user1");
            obj.put("firstName", "Antonio");
            obj.put("lastName", "Alves");

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        se.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPut.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

And all went fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of options trying solutions with HTTP Header, try adding the following key to Internet Explorer in Windows Registry if you are seeing 'No such Window exception' preeceded by 500 Internal Server Error. The following resolved the issue for me.

[Selenium - NoSuchWindowException in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746777/selenium-nosuchwindowexception-in-ie-11)