# Selenium - NoSuchWindowException in IE 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a webpage using selenium in IE11. I have set the protected mode settings to same level and zoom level is 100%. While running the test it opens the website however gives the exception just after. Below is the code used.

```
   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );       
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
   capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
   true); 
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

And the exception stacktrace

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.39.0.0
Listening on port 38122
Jul 11, 2014 1:50:02 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused        connection abort: recv failed
Jul 11, 2014 1:50:02 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on   closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
 System info: host: 'Neeraj', ip: '10.136.180.161', os.name: 'Windows 7',  s.arch: 'amd64',      os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'  Session ID: ab6edd65-8a66-41fa-be46-56fba7dbdfc9
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
 Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,                          ignoreZoomSetting=false,                                  enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true,   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, requireWindowFocus=false,  handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:38122/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:220)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
 at Test1.main(Test1.java:27)
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, don't use

```
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
```

as you have already set Protected mode settings. For the issue you are seeing, it should be because of the missing registry settings that is added as a prerequisite for running tests in IE11:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: Thanks. For anyone facing the same issue [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/registry/ht/open-registry-editor.htm) is the reference link for opening registry settings

Comment: The link for that configuration is now https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Answer (score 11):

I am using **IE 11 - 64 bit windows machine**. This point worked for me.

For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

> For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the
>   registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
>
> For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

**Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present.**

**Important:** Inside this key, create a `DWORD` value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of 0.

Comment: Wow that worked. But the input is freaking slow - a letter per minute :-/ Any idea?

Comment: Hope you are using a 64-bit machine and a 64-bit IE driver. Use a 32-bit IE driver instead.

Comment: I am using 64-bit machine. Added the relevant registry entry and change to 32-bit IE Driver. still getting the exception.

Comment: there is no main in internet explorer

Comment: Please ensure you are navigating under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Answer (score 8):

The solution suggested by @David Kemp is **not working for the ie 11 of windows 10 - 64 bit** . I have added  the registry key  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`  according to the steps mentioned For IE 11 only following https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration but after opening the https certificate page (url https://my-page:9443) it is unable to   execute             `driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");` throwing [NoSuchWindowException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchWindowException.html)

However same **works fine for ie 11 of windows 7-64 bit** and able to execute the scripts .

The  work around to make ie 11 work for win 10 is by setting **initialBrowserUrl** capabilities  to  **https://my-page:9443**  like below

```
capabilities.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl", "https://my-page:9443");
```

***but I am still confused why for ie11 / windows 10 it's different ?***

Answer (score 3):

Below solution also works if from current page you navigate on next page on some action/event and selenium driver doesnt recognise window :-

For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

Inside this create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I found that, if the launched browser is kept on focus, you will get that exception. As soon as you launch the webdriver, open any other window, for example, you can open eclipse as soon as the script launches IE Driver. Script execution starts, and then you can open you IE Driver.. to handle it through scripts, you add the below code:

```
    public WebDriver driver, driver1;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty(
                    "webdriver.ie.driver", "./BrowserDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe"));
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
            this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(WaitTimeConstants.WAIT_TIME_LONG, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            this.driver.get("yourApplication.com");
            this.driver.manage().window().maximize();

public WebDriver driver, driver1;
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty(
                "webdriver.ie.driver", "./BrowserDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe"));
        driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
        this.driver1.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        this.driver1.get("http://www.google.com");
        this.driver1.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Added domain of AUT to list of "Trusted Sites" for i.e. in "Internet Options". Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IE Options --> Security Tab -> Uncheck "Enable Protected Mode" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add http://localhost/ to your trusted sites in IE11. This worked for me,after trying everything else without results.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore above all... i have tried below line in my desired capabilities for IE driver then its worked .. :)

```
            ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a few options from below:

1. Use relative paths in the project, later you can choose to get its absolute path.
2. Setting the Protected mode setting for all, to either enabled or disabled.
3. Try understanding what really this exception mean "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on   closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds"

This states that whatever being done by your code (the web driver) is not able to identify the window of IE.

The possible causes can be:
a. Multiple driver instances are already running which were instantiated by older runs and could not have been terminated by quite().
b. The sometimes when you use close() on a driver it will not terminate the IE Driver, so use quite() after closing inside a finally block.
Yes, add some Exception handling to avoid the above issue.

4. Exception "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException" also suggests that web driver instance is not able to get the handle of IE's window tab. I faced this issue when accidentally, the browser was closed and the code was still trying to locate and do some action on a web element. In this case, the driver throws this exception to tell that there is no IE browser opened at all.
5. Having a check on the opening of browser can also help, I usually keep some piece of code that gives logs of used Driver object and the port where it is trying to connect and to which browser to.

For me, point 4 & 5 worked. but you might wanna just change the web driver's service i.e. browser. IE is just too slow sometimes to honour the selenium API calls :(