# selenium IWebdrivr throws no OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a IWebdriver pointing to a IE browser.

Every now and then, I cannot do anything, the driver seems to have lost connection and I get the message

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException
```

when nothing abnormal was done. This behavior occurs often, what might cause it?

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746777/selenium-nosuchwindowexception-in-ie-11

Comment: I've seen this happen when Selenium is being driven too hard.  For example a loop that keeps sending requests in rapid fire succession.  Selenium is a entire eco-system of it's own, its mostly bullet proof but it can be "hammered senseless".

Comment: @YuZhang Thanks, I added the registry thing. It now only happens on startup where it times out. Is there a reason?

Comment: @JohnPeters thanks!! However is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Try this, slow down your requests to Selenium.  Just to see if this works, then if that's the problem you should look into splitting the work across multiple instances of your driver. But also you may want to show us the code where this issue happens to give us a better idea of what's happening.   Or perhaps the stack trace too.

Comment: @JohnPeters thanks!! I forgot to mention that now it only happen when opening the driver, after adding the registry key in the link provided by Yu Zhang