# Browserstack - NoSuchWindowException in IE 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browserstack, selenium-iedriver

I am running my tests on browserstack and for **IE 11** I am getting following error when it tries to find element.

The same test runs successfully in **IE 10**.

**Code:**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("label[for='form:quest:0:quest:0:questionId:0']")));
```

**Exception:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window
```

I came across following post while trying to find the solution, however unsure how to set this capability in browserstack.

[Selenium - NoSuchWindowException in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746777/selenium-nosuchwindowexception-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 1):

This error is specific to the IEDrvier itself, while interacting with IE browsers. BrowserStack has added the following capability to fix the issue:

> "browserstack.bfcache" = "0"

Comment: I tried it however, it's not working. I have now capabilities set as you mentioned. 
`capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.bfcache", "0");`

Comment: If the capability does not work then you should contact BrowserStack's support team. May be share the session details with them.